# ifconfig -a not showing eth0

Tags: linux, rhel

When I type command `ifconfig` in my RHEL 7.3 Machine, it shows only `ens33, lo, virbr0, virbr0-nic`.

It is not showing `eth0`, is there any way to get `eth0`?

[image]

Comment: Device naming for network cards has changed.  https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/

Comment: Is this a virtualization, or is this RHEL installed directly on your computer?

Comment: its running on virtual machine.

Answer (score 2):

In this system you don't have this Ethernet Interface name, but the equivalent will be: `ens33`.

If you want to change the eth name check out the following link: [change interface name](https://www.shellhacks.com/change-network-interface-name-eth0-eth1-eth2/) and check the Centos/RHEL part.